# How do you violate the intermediate days of the festivals?

Tags: chol-hamoed, maseches-sanhedrin

The Talmud ([Sanhendrin 99a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=99&format=pdf)) states:

> He who defiles sacred objects, he who violates the intermediate days of the festivals, or he who embarrasses another person in public, even if they are learned in Torah and have done many good deeds, lose their portion in the eternal world.

Defiling sacred objects and embarassing others is pretty clear, but how exactly do you violate Hol Hamoed (intermediate days of the festivals)? The primary days of the festivals have the 39 melachot (except cooking), but the melachot don't apply during Chol Hamoed!

Comment: There are many things one can violate on the intermediate days, see here http://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed#Forbidden_work

Comment: What is your source that the melachot don't apply during chol hamoed?

Comment: @BabySeal From now deleted comment: "That's the whole reason it's called "Chol"--because you can do work."

Comment: http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/news/headlines-breaking-stories/264764/hilchos-chol-hamoed.html

Answer (score 2):

Not unlike Yom Tov, Melacha is forbidden on Chol Hamoed with certain exceptions. The opening line of the Shulchan Aruch's discussing these laws is (Shulchan Aruch OC 530):

> חול המועד אסור בקצת מלאכות ומותר במקצתן
>   Chol Hamoed is forbidden in some labors and permitted in some of them.

Violating these Melachot would constitute violating Chol Hamoed.

Comment: This answer could be improved if it contained more detail as to which melachot are off limits.

Comment: @BabySeal I don't know why that is relevant.

Comment: DoubleAA, Are you saying that if someone does anything the Shulchan Aruch forbids on Chol Hamoed, he loses his share in Olam Haba? That's a very strong statement.

Comment: @Ypnypn Which is why the gemara is aggadic. Its hyperbole

Comment: @Ramin There are large volumes written about the laws of Chol Hamoed. I am not going to reproduce them all here in one SE answer. Try searching Google for _melacha chol hamoed_.

Comment: @DoubleAA If it's just a subset of the 39 melachot then it can be  listed in just a couple of lines, but I see where you're coming from.