# Is one allowed to vote for an election candidate during chol hamoed?

Tags: politics-government, chol-hamoed, voting

It seems like it goes against the spirit of the holiday to have to go out of one's way to vote. But what if it's for the sake of Heaven (example being a candidate being more pro-israel)?

Comment: Are you asking about the melachot which might be involved, or about whether politics somehow goes against the spirit of the day? Related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27506/may-i-vote-stack-exchange-answers-up-or-down-during-chol-hamoed http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/70656/asking-answering-non-chag-related-questions-on-mi-yodeya-during-chol-hamoed http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38779/how-do-you-violate-the-intermediate-days-of-the-festivals/38787#38787

Comment: good clarification...let's say both for good measure.

Comment: Please define why you think it should not be allowed and define the parameters of what the spirit of the holiday means in a quantifiable way

Answer (score 2):

There are important elections now in Baltimore, and the local Rabbonim are encouraging voting on Chol Hamoed (if one wasn't able to utilize early voting, obviously) due to it being a tzorech for the community and other reasons.